# Powershell turns black on running command

Tags: powershell, terminal, windows-10

My original Powershell with a blue background looks quite good and easy to work with.:

[image: Original Terminal]

However on running certain commands like `conda` or `code`, it turns black, something like this:
[image: Terminal After running command]

Can anyone please tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your profile. And repeat and adapt for any other commands that have the same issue.

Some commands will alter the foreground, or background color. This should reset them. `$args` is a special variable that will contain everything after you type the function. It should function just like running the old command (which is (probably) really `conda.exe`). The `try/finally` is to make sure it always resets the colors, even if the program crashes or you press `Ctrl-C`

```bsh
Function conda {
    $fg = [console]::ForegroundColor
    $bg = [console]::BackgroundColor
    try {
        conda.exe $args
    } finally {
        [console]::ForegroundColor = $fg
        [console]::BackgroundColor = $bg
    }
}
```

To find your profile run this:

```bsh
$profile
```

If the file does not exist, create it, and add the above code.

Edit: Remember that after updating your profile, you need to either restart Powershell, or source your profile like this:

```bsh
. $profile
```

Comment: Yeah, I debate whether to include it, but it makes it more intentional that it's a command that should be run. I guess the text above makes it explicit, I will remove it.

Comment: Thanks for updating. In cases where you do want to be explicit, I suggest using `Write-Output` rather than `Write-Host`, unless there is a specific reason to use the latter.